# How to convert list object into multiple ints

Tags: python, python-3.x

Our homework requires us to make a game that sorts values of cards that appear in values of 1-20 + rock, paper, scissors + a coin flip. like this:

14 of paper heads

9 of scissor tails

We have to take a list of 30 of these and sort them by the value (the leading number), or the hand (rock, paper, scissors). We also have to be able to select a specific card and see if it is in the deck. I have a way to do this, but my current method stores each value in the list as a complete string.

```
import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self, id=0):
        self.id = id
        self.vals = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18",
                     "19", "20"]
        self.hands = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        self.coins = ["Heads", "Tails"]
        k = 0
    for v in self.vals:
        for h in self.hands:
            for c in self.coins:
                if k == self.id:
                    self.vals = v
                    self.hands = h
                    self.coins = c
                k += 1

def getVals(self):
    return self.vals

def getHands(self):
    return self.hands

def getCoins(self):
    return self.coins

def setVals(self, vals):
    self.vals = vals

def setHands(self, hands):
    self.hands = hands

def setCoins(self, coins):
    self.coins = coins

def __str__(self):
    return self.vals + " of " + self.hands + " " + self.coins

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18",
                     "19", "20"]
        self.hands = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        self.coins = ["Heads", "Tails"]
        self.deck = []
        for i in range(len(self.vals) * len(self.hands) * len(self.coins)):
            self.deck.append(Card(i))

def getDeck(self):
    return self.deck

def getVals(self):
    return self.vals

def getHands(self):
    return self.hands

def getCoins(self):
    return self.coins

def setDeck(self, deck):
    self.deck = deck

def setVals(self, vals):
    self.vals = vals

def setHands(self, hands):
    self.hands = hands

def setCoins(self, coins):
    self.coins = coins

def shuffle(self):
    random.shuffle(self.deck)

def returnDeck(self, num):
    return self.deck[num]
```

My current idea is to make each value divisible by a different numbers, but to do that I have to make each section of the object a different int.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `self.vals` to be a  list of `int`s. Here's how:

```
self.vals = [int(x) for x in self.vals]
```